# Android Studio AVD does not show Auto Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-automotive

I am following this official Android Tutorial :

[Developing for the Android Automotive OS Platform](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automotive-getting-started/#2)

After have changed to true of  the key in the studioFlags.xml

and restarted even the laptop

I still cannot see the automative emulator option as you can see from the screenshot [image]

I am on this Native Environment:

Ubuntu 18.04, 64bit
Android Studio 3.5.2

openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the Automative Emulator is still only available under the Android Studio 3.6 Beta 1 ( or > release )even if in the tutorial it mentioned 3.5 or superior.

Android Studio 3.6 Beta 1( called Android Studio Preview) or > is available here :

[Android Studio Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)